# Password does not save when installing VPN

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, vpn

I am trying to install a VPN on my app and the problem is that after installing it, IOS will prompt me for a password to the VPN even though it is specified in the code.

What is wrong with my code?

```
 @IBAction func Install(_ sender: Any) {


        NEVPNManager.shared().loadFromPreferences { error in
            // setup the config:
            let password = "vpnpass"
            let vpnhost = "us-west.windscribe.com"
            let p = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
            p.username = "vpnuser"
            p.serverAddress = vpnhost
            p.remoteIdentifier = vpnhost
            p.authenticationMethod = .none
            p.passwordReference = password.data(using: .utf8)!
            p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
            p.serverCertificateIssuerCommonName = vpnhost
            p.disconnectOnSleep = false


            print("Password:")
            print(password.data(using: .utf8)!)


            var rules = [NEOnDemandRule]()
            let rule = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
            rule.interfaceTypeMatch = .any
            rules.append(rule)

            NEVPNManager.shared().localizedDescription = "My VPN"
            NEVPNManager.shared().protocolConfiguration = p
            NEVPNManager.shared().onDemandRules = rules
            NEVPNManager.shared().isOnDemandEnabled = true
            NEVPNManager.shared().isEnabled = true
            NEVPNManager.shared().saveToPreferences { error in
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("NEVPNManager.saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
               VPNManager.sharedManager.startVPNTunnel()
            }
        }
```

Additionally, I cannot automatically start it in-app because  `VPNManager.sharedManager.startVPNTunnel()` is not recognized

Also, this comes up in the log:

```
2017-06-04 13:02:40.143478-0400 VPN[1212:157220] [] (null): SecItemCopyMatching failed: -50
```

Answer (score 0):

p.authenticationMethod = .none  Change it to NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodSharedSecret then it won't ask password anymore.

Thanks with regards